# Can someone help to achieve Netlix swiper hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, swiper.js

Can someone help me here, im trying to get netflix swiper effect. But when im hovering over card , the whole swiper position is getting changed.

And when i hover the card details also not getting smooth effect.

Im using bootstrap just for card.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <!-- Bootstrap  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .swiper {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      overflow:visible;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      transition: all 200ms ease-in 500ms;
      -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in 500ms;
    }
    .swiper-slide:hover{
      box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px 0px #000000;
      z-index: 50;
      transform: scale(1.5) !important;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) !important;
      top: -15px;
    }
    .swiper-slide img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }

    .swiper-container {
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .card {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .card-body{
      display: none;
      transition: all 200ms ease-in 500ms;
      -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in 500ms;
  
    }

    .swiper-slide:hover .card-body{
     display:block;
    }
    .swiper-slide:hover + .swiper-slide{
      z-index: 0;
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="swiper-container">


    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.rogerebert.com/uploads/review/primary_image/reviews/extraction-2-movie-review-2023/extraction-2-movie-review-2023.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
               <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and                   make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.rogerebert.com/uploads/review/primary_image/reviews/extraction-2-movie-review-2023/extraction-2-movie-review-2023.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
               <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and                   make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.rogerebert.com/uploads/review/primary_image/reviews/extraction-2-movie-review-2023/extraction-2-movie-review-2023.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
               <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and                   make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.rogerebert.com/uploads/review/primary_image/reviews/extraction-2-movie-review-2023/extraction-2-movie-review-2023.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
               <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and                   make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.rogerebert.com/uploads/review/primary_image/reviews/extraction-2-movie-review-2023/extraction-2-movie-review-2023.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
               <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and                   make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.rogerebert.com/uploads/review/primary_image/reviews/extraction-2-movie-review-2023/extraction-2-movie-review-2023.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
               <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and                   make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.rogerebert.com/uploads/review/primary_image/reviews/extraction-2-movie-review-2023/extraction-2-movie-review-2023.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
               <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and                   make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      // effect: "coverflow",
      slidesPerView: 6,
      spaceBetween: 30,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
      }
    });
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Also text size is not responsive.

[Click here to check my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-chebyshev-7ypqty?file=/index.html)